# How can aws api gateway listen to 2 lambda functions?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sns

My design is that api will trigger first lambda function, this function then send sns and return, sns triggers second lambda function. Now I want that api get the response from the second lambda function.

Here is the flow:
The api get the request from the user and then trigger the first lambda function, the first lambda function creates a sns and return. Now the api is at the lambda function stage and still waiting for the response from the second lambda. sns triggers the second lambda function; the second lambda function return some result and pass it to the api. api gets the response and send it back to user.

I know there is a way using sdk to get the second lambda function and set event type to make it async. But here I want to use sns, is it possible?

Need some help/advices.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid this design has a critical flaw. [SNS invokes Lambda asynchronously](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns) and there no result captured -- it is discarded.  If you need the result from a Lambda function, you need to invoke it synchronously so that your caller blocks waiting for the response.

Comment: As @Michael-sqlbot already mentioned, SNS won't be able to get the result of the invocation so your first Lambda won't be able to know the result from the second Lambda.

Comment: Also, SNS may call your second Lambda multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to share the lambda_func_2's return with lambda_func_1, the api gateway request context only return when you call `callback` on func1, you can not save or send the `request contex` to another lb_func.
My solution for this case is use Dynamodb (or every database) to share the f2's result.

F1 send data to sns, the date include a key like `transactionID` (uuid or timestamp). Then "wait" until F1 receive the result in table (ex: tbl_f2_result) and execute `callback` function with the result. Maybe query with `transactionID` until you receive data or only try 10 times (with time out 2s for one time, in worst case you will wait 20 seconds)

F2 has been trigged by SNS, do somthing with data include the `transactionID` then insert the result (success or not, error message ...) to result table(`tbl_f2_result`) with `transactionID` => `result`, callback finish F2.

`transactionID` is index key of table :D

You have to increase F1's timeout - Default is 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Lambda provides you a way to implement almost any arbitrary functionality that you want, whether it's inserting a record into your DynamoDB, reading an object from your S3 bucket, calculating the tax amount for the selected item on an e-commerce site, or simply calling an API.
Notice that here you don't need any event to call your api from the lambda, as simply you call the api directly.
As you are using Node, you can simply use an http request; something like this:

```
var options = {
  host: YOUR_API_URL,
  port: 80,
  path: 'REST_API_END_POINT',
  method: 'YOUR_HTTP_METHOD' //POST/GET/...
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  //Whatever you want to do with the reply...
}).end();
```

Comment: You are calling the api again, that is not what I want. The api already passes the request  stage, now is at the waiting for lambda response. Now instead of getting response from the first lambda function, I want the api get the response from the second lambda function and then enter the response stage and send the response to user.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what is possible for your problem, but requires polling.

#### API GTW

integration to --> Lambda1

#### Lambda1

1. create unique sha create a folder inside the bucket say s3://response-bucket/
2. Triggers SNS through sdk with payload having sha
3. Poll from the key s3://response-bucket/ ( with timeout set )
4. if result is placed then response is sent back from Lambda1 --> ApiGTW
5. if timeout then error is returned.

If success then trigger SNS for cleanup of response data in bucket with payload being SHA which will be cleaned up by another lambda.

#### SNS

Now the payload with the SHA is there in SNS

#### Lambda2

1. SNS triggers lambda2
2. pull out the unique sha from the payload
3. lambda result is placed in same s3://response-bucket/
4. exit from lambda2